# Create dynamic axios client

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I have a base axios client as:

```
import axios from "axios";

const httpClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://localhost:7254/test",
});

httpClient.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => config,
  (error) => Promise.reject(error)
);

httpClient.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => response,
  (error) => Promise.reject(error)
);

export default httpClient;
```

Then I use in my service as:

```
export const myService = createService(base);
```

This works as expected, but now I want to do the client dynamic to accept whatever controller, actually it has a static: `/test` `"https://localhost:7254/test"`

But I want to change it in oreder to do something like this on my services

```
 export const myService = createService(`{base}/test`);
```

How can I achieve that? Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `createService` currently accepts an instance of axios and you want to replace the baseURL inside the `createService`, then just do

```js
function createService(axiosInstance) {
  axiosInstance.defaults.baseURL = 'something/else/here'
}
```

Docs: https://axios-http.com/docs/config_defaults

---

The OP lacks a bit of context because there are some cases this is valid, but IMO, you seem to be doing the right thing.

Instead of replacing the baseURL somewhere, just set the proper value from the first place. Something like:

```js
const httpClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL,
});

createService(httpClient)
```